# No Microphone on CM12.1

Tags: cyanogenmod, 5.1-lollipop, microphone, samsung-galaxy-core-prime

My microphone stops working, when I upgraded to / installed [CM12.1](http://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-core-prime/development/rom-cyanogenmod-12-1-samsung-galaxy-t3405669) on my phone.

It is still working, when my phone still doesn't have CyanogenMod installed.

However, some apps, such as Cortana and calls (the stock calling app), can still detect / hear my voice; but **not** on Google's Voice Search, Sound Recorder, and such Microphone Apps on the Play Store.

Maybe, a library (`lib*.so`), permission not allowed (`android.permission. ...`), or somethin', is missing on my device, that is preventing the microphone to work.

> Phone:   Samsung Galaxy Core Prime
>
> Model:   SM-G360HU
>
> Recovery:   TWRP
>
> ROM:   CM12.1
>
> *- Link for the ROM can be found above ...*
>
> Android Version:   5.1 Lollipop

***Please HELP!***

---

### UPDATE

I've seen an app (I installed it), and it requires root access. After looking at the log of the root access of that app, it showing a library / lib named `libaudio_recorder_sf.so`.
Does this lib have to do with the microphone, or any recorder (e.g. Sound Recorder app) ?

Comment: Go post a bug report in the thread you linked.

Comment: I can't.  I don't have enough privileges to do such things ...

Comment: Just post more in other subforums such as General and Q&A. XDA is a very useful place, you'll find yourself coming back to it more later, so do take some time to do some quality posts and earn the privilege.

Comment: Hi, guys!  It's been a long time, and this question still got no answers, so I decided to edit the question with an update.  Hope you will find more answers than before.  :)

Answer (score 0):

This bug is fixed on CM13.  The microphone is now working, when I upgraded to CM13.